# Prevent user from closing Interstitial Ad for a few seconds

Tags: android, delphi, admob, interstitial, delphi-10.1-berlin

It is possible to prevent the user from closing an interstitial ad from AdMob for a few seconds? Google sent to my interstitial ad several ads that shows a 3-2-1 timer for closing the ad but when the user just tap Back the ad closes instantly.

```
type
TMyAdViewListener = class(TJavaLocal, JIAdListener)
private
FAD: JInterstitialAd;
public
constructor Create(AAD: JInterstitialAd);
procedure onAdClosed; cdecl;
procedure onAdFailedToLoad(errorCode: Integer); cdecl;
procedure onAdLeftApplication; cdecl;
procedure onAdOpened; cdecl;
procedure onAdLoaded; cdecl;
end;

private
LAdViewListener: TMyAdViewListener;
FInterStitial: JInterstitialAd;

var
  LADRequestBuilder: JAdRequest_Builder;
  LadRequest: JAdRequest;

procedure TForm53.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
FInterStitial := TJInterstitialAd.JavaClass.init(MainActivity);
FInterStitial.setAdUnitId
(StringToJString('ca-app-pub-1212/1212'));
end;

constructor TMyAdViewListener.Create(AAD: JInterstitialAd);
begin
inherited Create;
FAD := AAD;
end;
```

No actions are made in any TMyAdViewListener event

```
LADRequestBuilder := TJAdRequest_Builder.Create;
LADRequestBuilder.setGender(genero);
LADRequestBuilder.addTestDevice(MainActivity.getDeviceID);
LadRequest := LADRequestBuilder.build();
LAdViewListener := TMyAdViewListener.Create(FInterStitial);
CallInUIThread(
procedure
begin
  FInterStitial.setAdListener(TJAdListenerAdapter.JavaClass.init
    (LAdViewListener));
  FInterStitial.loadAd(LadRequest);
end);
```

And finally, a few time later shows it...

```
CallInUIThread(
procedure
begin
  LAdViewListener.FAD.show;
end);
```

But even setting if ((Key = vkHardwareBack)) then Key := 0; on both MainForm and the Form that calls the ad, the ad ignores it and close himself.

There is any way to prevent the ad closure for a few seconds or a few Back taps?

Comment: You can't do that. Even if you can, you shouldn't. How ads should be closed is decided by the advertiser, not you.

Comment: Actually, how ads should be closed should be decided by the user, not by the advertiser.

Comment: Yes, but all ads came with "X" button, "No, thanks" button, "Skip this Ad" button, and some came with 3 sec timer button to close it. I just want to prevent the user from ignoring all of them with a Back tap.